# TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures. stringify@[native code]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native expo project I am facing an error that says "TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures. stringify@[native code]" Can anyone can help me to fix this problem? i tried using a library called  "json-stringify-safe" but after using it like this "body: jsonStringifySafe(MessageData)," it was giving me react-navigation error  Can anyone can help me to fix this error?

```
   const SendMessage = async () => {
        const MessageData = {
            message: currentmessage,
            RoomId: roomid,
            SenderId: mydata._id,
            RecieverId: otheruser[0]._id
        };
        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/saveMessage', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(MessageData),
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.message === "Message Saved!") {
                    console.log("Message Saved!");
                    setCurrentMessage('');
                } else {
                    alert("Please, Try Again");
                }
            });
    };
```

My Backend:

```
router.post("/saveMessage", async (req, res) => {
    const { SenderId, RecieverId, message, RoomId } = req.body;

    try {
        const NewMessage = new Message({
            SenderId,
            RecieverId,
            message,
            RoomId
        })
        await NewMessage.save();
        res.send("Message Saved!")
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('error while saving message', err);
        res.status(422).send(err.message);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that you have a property on `MessageData` (or their descendants) that directly or indirectly end up referring to themselves. For instance:

```
const parent = { children: [] };
const child = { parent };
parent.children.push(child);
```

At this point, `parent` refers to `child` which refers to `parent`. If you did `JSON.stringify` on either of them (directly or indirectly), you'd get this error because JSON can't represent cyclical structures:

```js
const parent = { children: [] };
const child = { parent };
parent.children.push(child);
console.log(JSON.stringify(parent));
```

So you'll have to look at `MessageData` and the objects it refers to to find out where the cycle is. Note that it could be quite deep down:

```js
const parent = { children: [] };
const child = { parent };
parent.children.push(child);

const zero = {
    one: {
        two: {
            three: {
                parent
            },
        },
    },
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(zero));
```

Some JavaScript engines offer you more information about the cyclic structure than others. For instance, here's what V8 (the engine used by Chromium browsers and Node.js) says about the above:

> ```
> js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>     --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
>     |     property 'children' -> object with constructor 'Array'
>     |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'Object'
>     --- property 'parent' closes the circle
>     at JSON.stringify ()
>     at js:26:18
> ```

That's quite informative, more so than what you've quoted in your question. So you might try using a Chromium browser if you aren't already to replicate the issue in hopes it can give you more detail about where the cycle is.

Comment: Can i fix this problem with any kind of library in react native? my server is on hosted on a cloud platform

Comment: @Jack - I don't know of one, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist. But you can solve this by not having cycles in the data you're trying to send to the server.

Comment: confusing to me but I am using socket io in my server with nodejs

Comment: @Jack - It's nothing to do with socket.io or fetch. It's that you can't serialize a cyclic structure in JSON. JSON doesn't have that feature.

Comment: But my code is not working due to it

Comment: Right. So ***you*** have to fix (remove) the cycle in the data you're trying to convert to a JSON string.

Comment: can you please check my edited question? you can see what i am trying to do

Comment: @Jack - It's perfectly clear what you're trying to do, and I've told you what's wrong with it (JSON can't represent cyclical structures) and what to do about it (remove the cycle). I can't help you further than that.